# Creating Custom Content Packages For Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

### Background

So I have been trying and failing to make my own custom content packages for unreal engine 5 for a week now. I just want to extract portions of directories from certain projects and combine them into re-usable sets of content/code/etc. so I can re-import them into other projects.

I wasn't able to use "Migrate" because it always complained that it wasn't a "Content" folder (even though it was). I was able to generate a .upack file and simple copy the directories I wanted into my `Samples/FogBillboard/Content` directory. I was able to run the `UE_5.3\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealPak.exe` and have it generate the zip file for me and there were no errors and it said it captured a series of files. So it should* be fine?

I have copied the .upack file to `UE_5.3\FeaturePacks` and the `Samples/FogBillboard/Content` content to `UE_5.3\Samples\FogBillboard\Content`. However, when I go to `Add Feature or Content Pack` from the UnrealEngine I don't see the package I have generated.

### Question

**Has anyone come across this issue where you have generated the .upack file and samples content but it doesn't show up? Do you know of anything I can try?**

### Additional Details

#### Directory Structure

```
CustomContentPacks
+-ContentPack
  +-ContentSettings
    +-Config
      +-config.ini
    +-Media
      +-FogBillboard.png
      +-FogBillboard_Preview.png
    +-manifest.json
  +-FeaturePacks
    +-FogBillboard.upack
  +-Samples
    +-FogBillboard
      +-Content
        +-FX
           ...
  +-ContentToPack.txt
```

#### ContentToPack.txt

NOTE: `D:\...` is just a way to reduce the path size in this post.

```
D:\...\CustomContentPacks\ContentPack\ContentSettings\Config\
D:\...\CustomContentPacks\ContentPack\ContentSettings\Media\
D:\...\CustomContentPacks\ContentPack\ContentSettings\manifest.json
```

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "Version": 1,
    "Name": [
        {
            "Language": "en",
            "Text": "FogBillboard"
        }
    ],
    "Description": [
        {
            "Language": "en",
            "Text": "A blueprint that will display a simple billboard fog effect."
        }
    ],
    "AssetTypes": [],
    "SearchTags": [
        {
            "Language": "en",
            "Text": "Fog Billboard"
        }
    ],
    "ClassTypes": "",
    "Catagory": "Content",
    "Thumbnail": "FogBillboard.png",
    "Screenshots": [
        "FogBillboard_Preview.png"
    ]
}
```

#### config.ini

```
[AdditionalFilesToAdd]
+Files=Samples/FogBillboard/Content/*.*
```